# elasticsearch query_string term in term vector but not matching

Tags: elasticsearch

Having trouble getting a query_string query to match my document. Running a pretty simple query that I would expect to match given the terms. I've included the relevant output of a _termvector query of the document that I expect to match. And an explain query with the example I'm trying to do.

```
GET site/site_doc/dcb2ae16-da4e-11e5-94d8-0ac67484b577/_termvectors?fields=name,extras,amenities

{
  "_index": "site",
  "_type": "site_doc",
  "_id": "dcb2ae16-da4e-11e5-94d8-0ac67484b577",
  "_version": 2,
  "found": true,
  "took": 0,
  "term_vectors": {
    "extras": {
      "field_statistics": {
        "sum_doc_freq": 30,
        "doc_count": 10,
        "sum_ttf": 37
      },
      "terms": {
        "bullet": {
          "term_freq": 1,
          "tokens": [
            {
              "position": 101,
              "start_offset": 5,
              "end_offset": 12
            }
          ]
        },
        "gun": {
          "term_freq": 1,
          "tokens": [
            {
              "position": 0,
              "start_offset": 0,
              "end_offset": 4
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
   ...
}
```

And the output of explain

```
GET site/site_doc/dcb2ae16-da4e-11e5-94d8-0ac67484b577/_explain
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "gun"
    }
  }
}

{
  "_index": "site",
  "_type": "site_doc",
  "_id": "dcb2ae16-da4e-11e5-94d8-0ac67484b577",
  "matched": false,
  "explanation": {
    "value": 0,
    "description": "no matching term",
    "details": []
  }
}
```

I had to explicitly set

```
query.querystring.fields=['extras', 'amenities']
```

to find terms in those fields. I'm not really sure of why or how it's making it work so I won't answer my own question if anyone wants to explain or point to documentation.

Here is the mapping of the index

```
{
  "site": {
    "mappings": {
      "site_doc": {
        "properties": {
          "amenities": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "snowball"
          },
          "extras": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "snowball"
          },
          "headline": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "snowball"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have something like `"_all": { "enabled": false }` in the mapping's settings? If not, can you show the mapping of the index?

Comment: I don't. I've edited the post with the mapping.